# How to change the value of a TextInput using reference in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native `0.57.8` and React `16.7.0`. I am creating an on-screen keyboard for Android TV which will be used as a library. I have a `TextInput` to whom I have assigned a reference. How can I use this reference to change the `value` of the `TextInput`?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.emailRef = React.createRef();
}

<TextInput
  ref={this.emailRef}
  placeHolder="Email Address"
  blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

<Keyboard textInput={this.emailRef} />
```

Inside the library:

```
<Button
  text="change value"
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.emailRef.current.props.value =
      this.props.emailRef.current.props.value + "q";
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using state for the values? For example: `value={this.state.value}` in your TextInput

Comment: @JRK Yes, I am creating an on-screen keyboard for Android TV which will be used as a library.

Comment: So why can't you use state?

Comment: Are the TextInput and Button within the same component?

Comment: @markmoxx The keyboard as a whole is imported as a component. The value will be updated inside the `onPress` of each of the buttons inside the library. The state of the screen can't be updated from there.

Comment: @markmoxx No, they are not within the same component.

Comment: Is your TextInput really a text input, i.e. can you type directly into it, or is it just controlled by the buttons? In other words, does it really need to be a TextInput?

Comment: @markmoxx It is an RN TextInput. It's on Android TV so it is unfocusable and uneditable which is why an onscreen keyboard is required to change its value.

Comment: @khateeb check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a prop directly within the component - Props can only be derived from a parent component, but cannot be modified, so you can't do:

`this.props.emailRef.current.props.value = this.props.emailRef.current.props.value + "q";`

Also, you reference `this.props.emailRef` in your library, whereas the keyboard doesn't have the `emailRef` prop - it has the `textInput` prop.

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.emailRef = React.createRef();
  this.state = {
    value: "Initial Input"
  };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}

handleInput(input) {
  this.setState({ value: input });
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
      <Keyboard textInput={this.emailRef} onInput={this.handleInput} />
      <TextInput ref={this.emailRef} value={this.state.value} />
    ...
  );
}
```

Inside the library:

```
<Button
  text="change value"
  onClick={() => {
    this.props.onInput(this.props.textInput.current.props.value + "q");
  }}
/>
```

Comment: 'value' is a read-only property. Use `setNativeProps` function

Answer (score 17):

Use state they all say without knowing why I exactly need to update UI without using state. In my case the text input was using state, and when typed really fast, the asynchronous state and UI update lags behind the speed of typing, and cursor lags couple of letters behind causing in errors in typing. Only way to prevent this is not to use any state! if you do not use state, you cannot give text input an initial value without making it readonly. To give TextInput an initial value, we can use ref and set native props programmatically upon component mount event. like so:

```
const setInitialBio = React.useCallback(() => {
    if(inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.setNativeProps({ text: "initial value goes here" })
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Update on what I did: I am using `MentionInput` component from [react-native-controlled-mentions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-controlled-mentions) instead of `TextInput`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a controlled input. 
Here is how I would do that:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.emailRef = React.createRef(); // might not need this
  this.state = {
    value: ''
  }
}

<TextInput
  value={this.state.value}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
  placeHolder="Email Address"
  blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

<Button
  text="change value"
  onPress={() => {
    // just use `this.state.value` to do whatever you need with it
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set text in state method then update state in pressed button

then set in text like this

```
<Text>
       {this.state.myText}
    </Text>
```