# REACT ADMIN | TEXTINPUT CHANGE VALUE

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

how can I change the value of an `TextInput` in `react-admin`.

My idea was

```
<TextInput label="..." source="..." value="MY VALUE" />
```

But that doesn't work.
pls help.

Comment: does this help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214114/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-textinput-using-reference-in-react-native

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with the `react-admin`'s `TextInput` as it is a connected field to the backing `react-final-form` form and hence you don't control the input.

You should state what is your final aim. I can think of two options:

1. If you want to have a controlled input you can simply use `material-ui`'s `TextField` and pass to it your custom `value` as well as handle the `onChange` event.
2. If you don't want to control the value by yourself but alter it in the form state under some condition, you can then use the hook provided by `react-final-form`:

   ```
   const form = useForm();
   form.change("myValue", newValue);
   ...
   <TextInput label="My Value" source="myValue"  />
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Since `react-adminv4.0.0` library no longer uses `react-final-form` instead it uses `react-hook-form`. So you would need to change your relevant code to use it as well.

```
import {useFormContext} from "react-hook-form";
...
const {setValue} = useFormContext();
setValue("myValue", newValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the value of your input is null or undefined you can use the `initialValue` prop to set the value when the page loads.

`<TextInput source="mySource" initialValue="MY VALUE" />`

See React-Admin Input Docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props

If you are looking to dynamically change the value after the page has loaded, I would recommend following Kia's answer to leverage the `useForm` hook.